# One-to-many promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a list of customers, and then each customer has a series of tasks to be run.  In psudeocode:

```
Get all customers
For each customer, get list of tasks
For each task, run task
```

However, I want to take advantage of JavaScript's async nature when running these tasks.  With promises I can do something like:

```
getAllCustomers().then(function(customers) {
  var taskGetters = [];
  customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    taskGetters.push(getCustomerTasks(customer).then(function(tasks) {
      var taskDoers = [];

      tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        taskDoers.push(doTask());
      });

      return promise.all(taskDoers);
    });
  });

  return promise.all(taskGetters);
}).then(function() {
  // clean up
}).catch(function() {
  // handle error
});
```

However, this encounters some of the structural problems callbacks have - I'm starting to nest things instead of keeping the clean psudeo-synchronous structure promises should have.  How can I solve this while retaining the structural advantages of promises?

Comment: How would `Promise.all` over an array of arrays even work? It would resolve immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall you are using bluebird, so you can just:

```
getAllCustomers().map(function(customer) {
  return Promise.map(customer, getCustomerTasks).map(doTask);
}).then(function() {

}).catch(function() {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum D:

Answer (score 1):

> However, this encounters some of the structural problems callbacks have - I'm starting to nest things instead of keeping the clean psudeo-synchronous structure promises should have.

No. Even the synchronous equivalent would be nested: you are having two loops there:

```
customers = getAllCustomers()
for each customer in customers
  tasks = getTasklist()
  for each task in tasks
    run(task)
```

However, for cleaner code I would recommend to use `map` instead of `forEach` with manual array building:

```
getAllCustomers()
.then(function(customers) {
  return promise.all(customers.map(function(customer) {
    return getCustomerTasks(customer)
    .then(function(tasks) {
      return promise.all(tasks.map(doTask));
    });
  }));
}).then(function() {
  // clean up
}).catch(function() {
  // handle error
});
```

Some promise libraries might even offer a shortcut method for the `.then((X)=>all(X.map(…)))` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Id you make each of your callbacks a function, rather than a closure, you will have a nicer structure:

```
function processTasks(tasks){
  var taskDoers = [];

  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
    taskDoers.push(doTask());
  });

  return promise.all(taskDoers);
}

function processCustomer(customer){
    taskGetters.push(getCustomerTasks(customer).then(processTasks));
}

function processCustomers(customers){
    customers.forEach(processCustomer);
}

function cleanup(){

}
function handle(error){

}
getAllCustomers().then(processCustomers).then(cleanup).catch(handle);
```

You can separate as many of the closures into functions as you like.

Comment: This is flat, but hard to read - kind of like flat callback code.